# Disable Gnome classic desktop hot corner

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Is there a way to disable Gnome classic desktop hot corner (upper left corner)?  I activate it accidentally far more often than I do intentionally which is quite annoying. I have a Fn+whatever key that will do the same thing, so I don't really need the hot corner.

Comment: Actually, its the System (Super) key that lets me access the hot corner screen, not a Fn+whatever key.  At any rate, the hot corner is obnoxious and I don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that throught the **gnome-tweak-tool**... it should be listed there along with your default extensions...

However if your case is like mine, you won't find the default extension there and will have to install one by yourself, I've installed the one below and the  "No topleft hot corner" extension started to show up on my extension list...

https://github.com/HROMANO/nohotcorner/archive/master.zip

Also here's the thread where I've found the extension:

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48130

Comment: I didn't figure out how to install it from the download, but I was able to install it from [https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) .  It works as advertised.  Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help!